# Make every two elements the same height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container with a number of children that needs to be the same height, only in pairs of two tho.
for example the first and second element needs to be as high as the highest of the two and the third and forth need to be as high as whichever is highest, independent of the height of the first and second child.

My current code, which equals all children heights

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Select and loop the container element of the elements you want to equalise
        $('.parent').each(function(){

            // Cache the highest
            var highestBox = 0;

            // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
            $('.child', this).each(function(){

                // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
                if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
                    highestBox = $(this).height();
                }

            });

            // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest
            $('.child',this).height(highestBox);

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no clue what you trying to archive. Could you add the html and an better explanation (e.g. an image) what the expected result should look like?

Comment: You could wrap the pairs of children into flexboxes and use `align-items: stretch`

Comment: Please add the HTML.... are the 'pairs' wrapped in an element?

Comment: @users3154108 wrapping every 2 element ain't a stupid idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope something like below you are looking for. May be using `flex` is simplest way of getting it done. Here i tried with some jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Cache the highest
  var highestBox = 0;
  var loop = 1
  // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
  $('.child', this).each(function() {
    if (loop % 2 != 0) {
      // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
      highestBox = $(this).height();
      if ($(this).next('.child').height() > highestBox) {
        highestBox = $(this).next('.child').height();
      }

      // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest
      $(this).height(highestBox);
      $(this).next('.child').height(highestBox);
    }
    loop++;

  });

});
```

```css
.child {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content
    some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content some dynamic content</div>
  <div class='child'>some dynamic content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're probably want to achieve grid-like behavior, it can be easily achieved without JavaScript using flexbox:

```css
  /* Purely for visual appearance */
.parent {
  width: 300px;  
}
.child {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, lightgreen, yellow);
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Actual logic */
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.child {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>a bit of text</div>
  <div class='child'>very large amount of content to make height largest across all rows</div>
  <div class='child'>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</div>
  <div class='child'>a b c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example **all** the children have the same height. The TS want the height equal in pairs of two.

Comment: @LinkinTED you're wrong, I've updated answer to demonstrate it